# SQL - Correct dates not being presented in result set with date ranges in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, where-clause

Result set without the where clause shows there is data from the 30th September, when using the below where clause the 30th data doesn't come through in the result set (see images below for result sets) - **my main aim is to show data from between the first day of the previous month and the last day of the previous month** - Any help is much appreciated:

### SQL Query

```
DECLARE @date1 datetime
DECLARE @date2 datetime
SET @date1 = getdate()
SET @date2 = getdate()-15 -- reason for less 15 days is because this will only be run within the first 15 days 
                          -- of the current month, it will enable me to get the last day of the previous 
                          -- month even if I run the SQL in the next month.

SELECT
        A.TA_SEQ as 'WO No',
        A.TA_DUE_DATEUTC

FROM 
        F_TASKS A WITH (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN FINFILE B WITH (NOLOCK) ON A.TA_FKEY_IN_SEQ = B.IN_SEQ 
        INNER JOIN InstructionSetGroups C WITH (NOLOCK) ON B.InstructionSetGroupId = C.InstructionSetGroupId 

WHERE
        A.TA_TASK_DESC = 'BREAKDOWN' AND
        A.TA_STATUS IN ('ACTIVE', 'ASSIGNED', 'COMPLETE', 'HISTORY') AND
        A.TA_DUE_DATE >= DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(@date1, -2)) AND
        A.TA_DUE_DATE <= EOMONTH(@date2) 

ORDER BY 
        A.TA_DUE_DATE desc
```

### Result Sets

*Result set using date ranges in where clause:*

> [image: Blockquote]

*Result set without using date ranges in where clause - as you can see there's lots of data from the 30th too which isn't being captured*

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: When comparing date ranges with a time component, I suggest an inclusive start date and exclusive end date. Try adding a day to the end date and change the operator to less than: `A.TA_DUE_DATE < DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH(@date2))`

Comment: Stop splatternig `NOLOCK` everywhere, it's not a g-faster switch, it's a give-incorrect-results switch

Comment: The data you are getting is correct. For example the `datetime` `2021-09-30 00:00:00.003` isn't equal to or **less than** `2021-09-30`, it's greater than it (by 1/300 seconds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EOMONTH` is terribly ambiguous, because it returns the last day of the month *at midnight*. I talk about why I don't like this function in [Will you use EOMONTH()?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/22/sql-server-v-next-denali-will-you-use-eomonth)

If you want the whole previous month, there are easier and safer ways than assuming the code will run within the first 15 days:

```
DECLARE @ThisMonth date = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1);

SELECT ... FROM ...
  WHERE TA_DUE_DATE >= DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @ThisMonth)
    AND TA_DUE_DATE <  @ThisMonth;
```

I explain why `DATEFROMPARTS` is best suited for this kind of work in [Simplify Date Period Calculations in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6088/simplify-date-period-calculations-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand).

With the rest, where do we begin?

- `getdate()-15` is lazy, unintuitive shorthand that will break in other contexts. Please use `DATEADD(DAY, -15, GETDATE())` and see [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations).
- You can declare/set in a more readable way than an explicit line for each declare and again for each set:

  ```
   DECLARE @date1 datetime = GETDATE(),
           @date2 datetime = DATEADD(DAY, -15, GETDATE());
  ```
- `as 'WO No'` - please use `AS [Wo No]` or `AS "Wo No"` - string delimiters make those aliases look like, well, strings, and some forms of that syntax are deprecated.
- please [always specify the schema](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix) and [never use meaningless aliases like `A`, `B`, `C`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3).
- `>= AND <=` is the same as `BETWEEN`. I talk about why `BETWEEN` is always a terrible idea for date ranges in [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
- Lots of resources on `NOLOCK` in [I'm using NOLOCK; is that bad?](https://sqlblog.org/nolock)
- General date tips in [Dating responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates)

Answer (score 1):

I would take a different approach to handling your date values. That whole -15 stuff is bizarre and will cause issues on days towards the end of the month. Instead using a single variable is sufficient if you understand some date math.

```
DECLARE @date1 date --use the data datatype here because time is important in this case
SET @date1 = getdate()

--this is to show you the values and can be removed.
select BeginningOfLastMonth = dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @date1) - 1, 0)
    , BeginningOfCurrentMonth = dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @date1), 0)

--Your select statement here
where A.TA_DUE_DATE >= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @date1) - 1, 0)
        A.TA_DUE_DATE <= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @date1), 0) --ANY datetime value less than this is before the end of last month
```

Comment: Yes! But why not `DATEFROMPARTS`? [So much tidier](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6088/simplify-date-period-calculations-in-sql-server/).

Comment: @AaronBertrand good point. Old habits die hard don't they? Had all sorts of oddball date math stuff saved for years now.

Comment: They sure do, for ages I put data types in upper case and have a hard time kicking that habit, also can't get away from lazy shorthand like `RTRIM` as a shorter `toString` than a proper `CONVERT`.